# Variational Principle for a System of Differential Equations

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

I am studying a differential operator of the form $$ L\left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ v \end{array}\right) = -\Delta \left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ v \end{array}\right) + V(x)\left(\begin{array}{c} u \\ v \end{array}\right) $$ where $V: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow M_{2\times 2}$ is smooth. Suppose further that $V$ is *not* of the form where the operator $L$ can be reduced to considering two separate scalar problems (e.g. $V$ is not diagonal, upper triangular, or lower triangular for all $x$). Does anyone know of a reference that talks about a variational principle for such an operator? I am mostly interested in the smallest eigenvalue of $L$ and the eigenspace of the smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: If your $V(x)$ is a symmetric matrix, then the variational principle is simply $\int w\cdot Lw\, d^n x$, where $w = \begin{pmatrix} u & v\end{pmatrix}^T$. If you wish, you can add a total divergence term to $-w\cdot \Delta w$ to make it look like $\nabla w \cdot \nabla w$.

Comment: Existence of the Principal Eigenvalue for Cooperative Elliptic Systems in a General Domain, Birindelli,  Mitidier & Sweers 1997 and references therein

Comment: @Athanagor Thanks for the reference, I really appreciate it! I'll take a look at it.